# How to code a WMD plug-in for Elgg?

Tags: wmd, elgg

How do I code a WMD plug-in for the [Elgg](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Elgg_%28software%29) framework?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You should first study and understand views in Elgg. They are like blocks in [Drupal](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Drupal), but have a wider context, like an include file. Elgg plug-ins now have a better structure, so you better go on with the newest version.

For the client-side JavaScript part, examine the [TinyMCE](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/TinyMCE) related views, there you can see an example showing how to replace the text editor window. Then include your PHP functions in the plug-in's main file. Any initialization functions should be called in the `init()` function of your plug-in.